# Build Errors with Cordova and Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am having some difficulty trying to understand why Visual Studio uses a different version of Node and NPM than what is installed...

My Development Environment Details:
-Windows 8.1
-Node Version: 6.10.3 (node -v)
-NPM Version: 5.0.1 (npm -v)

When I open up a solution file I get the following messages in my NPM Output window

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;%VSINSTALLDIR%\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\Web\External\npm.CMD" install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! No compatible version found: ionic-native@3.5.0
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["2.9.0","2.8.1","2.8.0","2.7.0","2.6.0","2.5.1","2.5.0","2.4.1","2.4.0","2.3.2","2.3.1","2.3.0","2.2.17","2.2.16","2.2.15","2.2.14","2.2.13","2.2.12","2.2.11","2.2.10","2.2.9","2.2.8","2.2.7","2.2.6","2.2.5","2.2.4","2.2.3","2.2.2","2.2.1","2.2.0","2.1.9","2.1.8","2.1.7","2.1.6","2.1.5","2.1.4","2.1.3","2.1.2","2.0.3","2.0.2","2.0.1","2.0.0","1.3.27","1.3.26","1.3.25","1.3.24","1.3.23","1.3.22","1.3.21","1.3.20","1.3.19","1.3.18","1.3.17","1.3.16","1.3.15","1.3.14","1.3.13","1.3.12","1.3.11","1.3.10","1.3.9","1.3.8","1.3.7","1.3.6","1.3.5","1.3.4","1.3.3","1.3.2","1.3.1","1.3.0","1.2.4","1.2.3","1.2.2","1.2.1","1.2.0","1.1.1","1.1.0","1.0.12","1.0.11","1.0.10","1.0.9","1.0.8","1.0.7"]
npm ERR!
```

The error messages say Visual studio is trying to use node v5.4.1 and npm  v3.3.4.... Where are these versions installed?  And why isn't it using Node 6.10.3 and NPM 5.0.2?

Any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old `ionic-native` package in your application. You should uninstall it by issuing the below command,

```
npm uninstall --save ionic-native
```

And then try installing the latest one by issuing the below `npm install` command,

```
npm install @ionic-native/core --save
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks David...The issue with the ionic-native version came down to some odd referencing in the project...this all started when I inherited the project from another developer who had the @3.5.0 version in the package.json file...having since spoken to the developer and he did a "Restore Package" he is now getting the same error message as me with respect to the missing ionic-native libraries..

Comment: He and I have no idea how the solution initially got the @3.5.0 version referenced, but we've since removed the ionic-native and replaced with ionic-native/core as you suggested.   But..my initial question was about the versions that are being listed in the build window..in this case. `npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4`  even though I have Node 6.10.3 and NPM 5.0.2 installed...but those versions are being displayed in the output window